# Robocopy all files except with particular character in filename

Tags: regex, robocopy

Using `robocopy` command I need to copy all files, but exclude files with particular character in the filename? For examlple copy all .jpg files with filenames containing underscore _ in it.

I have tried this command, but it doesn't work:

`Robocopy C:\SourceFolder C:\DestFolder ^[^_]+.jpg$`

Could be something really simple I'm overlooking here, but what?

There is also [/XF flag](https://superuser.com/questions/831023/windows-use-robocopy-to-copy-all-files-except-sas7bdat) to exclude certain file types, but (how) can it be used to exclude filenames containing the underscore in the filename?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think robocopy supports regular expressions, but it does support wildcards (that is, the asterisk `*`).

So you'd include these wildcards when telling it what files to exclude using the [`/XF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy#file-selection-options) flag.

```
robocopy *.jpg C:\source C:\dest /XF *_*.jpg
```

This works if the `_` is at the beginning, middle, or end of the file.

If you have multiple characters to wanted to exclude (say, exclude files that have underscores (`_`) and dashes (`-`)) then just add another wildcard statement after the `/XF` flag. You can list multiple parameters there, separated by spaces.

So something like

```
robocopy *.jpg C:\source C:\dest /XF *_*.jpg *-*.jpg
```